# nested_form giving me error wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
Extracted source (around line #):

```
enter code here
<%= f.text_field :name %>
# <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
<%= task_form.text_field :fname %>
<%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :tasks, ModelName.new do |task_form| %>
```

Thanks.